# Perl - byte swaping after reading the probe values

Tags: perl, swap

i need help in Perl. Maybe for you an easy question to answer... 
From from AD Converter i get values like 0X43b7 on an debian wheezy.
I read this values with the i2cget command

```
$EC = `sudo i2cget -y 1 0x4a 0x00 w` ;
```

what i get is an hex value 0x34c2. The used microcontroller did somethink like an little endian to this value and i need the swap the higher value bytes against the lower value bytes. I get an hint, but in python ... i had no glue how to handle this. Is there an easy expression in Perl for this Python line`?

```
           assert line.startswith("0x")
           word = int(line[2:], 16)
           yield struct.unpack(">H", struct.pack("<H", word))[0]
```

I never swaped bytes in Perl and not realy shure how to translate this.

Comment: What's the contents of $EC? Is it the string `0x34c2`, or `"\x34\xc2"`? And what's the expected output?

Comment: $EC is my variable, which contents the direct output of an A/D Converter over an i2c bus on an raspberry. The values i get lookslike this:
0x8600
0x6d00
0x8a00
0x6e00
0x7800
0x7000
0x7d00
0x8000
0x8700
0x7700
0x7400
0x7300
0x7600
0x9000
0x7a00

in need to remove "0x" an swap the first two bytes agains the last two bytes.

Comment: Don't expect those who know Perl to know Python well or at all. The input appears to be the string `0x34c2`, but what output do you want for that input? The string `c234`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input is the string `0x34c2` and you want to get the bytes `43 2c` (or the string "432c") back, you can use

```
my $EC = "0x34c2";
my $output = pack 'h4', substr $EC, 2;  # --> \x43\x2c
my $string = unpack 'H4', $output;      # --> "432c"
```

If you just want to swap the "bytes" in a string, you can use substitution

```
my $EC = "0x34c2";
(my $output = $EC) =~ s/(..)(..)$/$2$1/;
```

or [substr](http://p3rl.org/substr):

```
my $EC = "0x34c2";
my $output = $EC;
substr $output, 4, 0, substr $output, 2, 2, q();
```

Comment: Thanks for this - that seems easy to handle. What i get from this code is $EC = 0x1e00 -> result is e100

Thats close to that what i need -> my result should looklike

0x1e04 > 041e

Thanks for all here helping me here :)

Comment: @4zap: Check the update.

Comment: Missing `$output = hex($output);` to match the OP's code.

Comment: Thank you both...

[code]#!/usr/bin/perl
 
my $dir = '/var/www/motion';

my $EC = `sudo i2cget -y 1 0x4a 0x00 w` ;

print "$EC";

my $output = $EC;
substr $output, 4, 0, substr $output, 2, 2, q();

print "$output";

$ECdec=hex($output)/10;

                



print "Electric Conductivity $ECdec µS/m \n";
[/code]

works for me as expected! Thank you both for the fast solution! Made my day!

Answer (score 1):

You weren't clear about what output you want, but I determined the following by running your snippet:

For input, you have a string such as `0x34c2`.

For output, you want the number 49716<sub>10</sub> = C234<sub>16</sub>.

There are many different approaches you could use.

```
die("assert") if substr($s, 0, 2) ne "0x";

my $n = unpack('S<', pack('H*', substr($s, 2)));    # If it's a LE uint16_t
  -or-
my $n = unpack('s<', pack('H*', substr($s, 2)));    # If it's a LE int16_t
```

Alternatively,

```
my $n = unpack('S<', pack('S>', hex($s)));          # If it's a LE uint16_t
  -or-
my $n = unpack('s<', pack('s>', hex($s)));          # If it's a LE int16_t
```

Both solutions will work on both little-endian and big-endian platforms.

---

From the comments, it seems the next line should be the following:

```
my $ECdec = $n/10;
print "Electric Conductivity $ECdec µS/m\n";
```

---

```
$ python <<'EOS'
import struct
line = "0x34c2"
assert line.startswith("0x")
word = int(line[2:], 16)
word = struct.unpack(">H", struct.pack("<H", word))[0]
print word
EOS
49716

$ perl -e'
   use feature qw( say );
   my $s = "0x34c2";
   die("assert") if substr($s, 0, 2) ne "0x";
   my $word = unpack("S<", pack("H*", substr($s, 2)));
   say $word;
'
49716
```

Comment: I get a decimal output here - for exampe0x9802 results in 654

Comment: No you don't. "Decimal" is the string representation of a number. Like your python code, my snippet returns a *number*, not a string (decimal or otherwise). If that's not what you want, then fix your question because that's what you asked for. (Short answer: If you want to print the number out in hex, then don't print it out in decimal!)

Comment: Sorry if you missunderstood me, i am not a native speaker and for me it s sometimes difficult to understand questions the right way... but however...both codes helped me solve my problem. Thanks for that!

Comment: `my $ECdec = $n/10; print "Electric Conductivity $ECdec µS/m \n";`